# Как определить включил ли пользователь google translate на сайте с помощью js

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, google-chrome, google-translate

Я имеею в виду вот эту штуку:

[image]

Могу ли я как то отслеживать, включает ли пользователь сайта перевод с помощью js?

Comment: у тебя html меняется атрибут `lang`, и добавляется класс `translated-*` где вместо `*` может быть `ltr` либо `rtl`

Comment: @Grundy, ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При использовании google translate встроенного в Chrome корневому элементу `html` меняется атрибут `lang` на целевой, при переводе на русский будет установлено

```
lang="ru"
```

А так же добавляется класс вида `translated-*`, где вместо `*` может быть `ltr` либо `rtl` в зависимости от направления для целевого языка.

Таким образом для отслеживания перевода, достаточно следить за атрибутами элемента `html`, например с помощью [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

```
var observer = new MutationObserver((mutations)=>{
    var classMutation = mutations.find(m => m.attributeName === 'class');
    var langMutation =  mutations.find(m => m.attributeName === 'lang');

    if ((classMutation?.target.classList.contains('translated-ltr') ||
         classMutation?.target.classList.contains('translated-rtl')) && langMutation) {
        console.log('translated to', langMutation.target.lang);
    }
});

observer.observe(document.documentElement, { attributes: true });
```